# Please give a link to MiKTeX 2.9 for Windows XP

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I have  downloaded file (from the site https://miktex.org/download ) `basic-miktex-2.9.6643.exe` but I can't run it under my Windows XP. Please give me any link to install files for any working release for XP after October 2017.

Comment: Per requirements: https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites, WinXP is not supported. WinXP is not even supported by Microsoft anymore.

Comment: You may have more luck trying another TeX distribution, e.g. TeX Live. If the newest version does not run you may try an older one (they are archived).

Comment: @TeXnician there might be tl bins for Winxp for older tls, but I don't think Winxp will be supported in tl18

Comment: @daleif I don't know, but therefore one could use older binaries. If the OP really insists on using XP why shouldn't he use an outdated distro?

Comment: @TeXnician that is what the OP will have to do. I'm not sure if MikTeX have older versions available, TL versions are available via FTP:  ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive

Comment: @daleif No, MikTeX uses a rolling update system, so there is no real option to provide "older" versions.

Comment: I just asking for instal files for MickTex 2.9.6500 (for instance)

Comment: @Leox This is not possible: current MiKTeX simply doesn't support Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment of this writing, I was able to find *MiKTeX 2.9.5105* at [ftp.lip6.fr](ftp://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/TeX/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/setup/basic-miktex-2.9.5105.exe) (and a couple of other FTP servers, use the [www.filesearch.ru](http://www.filesearch.ru) engine), and *MiKTeX 2.9.3972* at [miktex.en.softonic.com](https://miktex.en.softonic.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately, to me MiKTeX installer from the first link refuses to work under Windows XP 32 bit SP3, and as for the second link the file wasn't found on softonic.com. +1 for www.filesearch.ru though:)